# scp returns a content of PATH variable instead of working

Tags: ssh, scp

I can't make `scp` work anymore.

I enter in my terminal:

```
scp myfile user@ip_address:/Users/user/myfile
```

It asks me my `password` and having entered that, it displays this line without copying anything:

```
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**Note** `ssh` still works fine. `scp` was working well before, I don't know what suddenly has changed. I am on Mac OSX 10.9.4

Edit: The problem comes from the remote machine because it works fine with other remote machine.

Comment: Has `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, or `$HOME/.bashrc` changed recently on the remote server?

Comment: Do you also get that line when you log into the remote host interactively (through ssh, not scp)?

Comment: @Mike : no, I don't remember having made any change on these files. (By the way I don't have any `$HOME/.bash_profile` on my server, I only have `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.profile`, but I don't think it could be related to the problem.) For information, `which scp` on the remote server returns `/usr/bin/scp`. @Kenster: no, logging with ssh goes normally and don't display this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. For some reason, the line `echo $PATH` appeared in my `.bashrc`. That's why the command was displaying my path and was making fail scp. Removing this line resolved the problem.